# why does objectify return inconsistent data?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am using the google datastore with objectify 4.0.1 to store messages.  Each message has a list of Comments attached.

Message id 5708313257836544 has 16 comments. At 10:34:08 a 17th comment is added.  A GET at 12:01:46 shows the message has 17 comments, another at 12:02 shows it has 16, and the following at 12:04 returns 17 again.  No comments have been deleted.

The code is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Message  {
    @Id private Long id;

    private List<Comment> comments;
    //getters and setters
  //equals and hashcode over-ridden using id
}



@Embed
public class Comment  {

    private String message;
    private Date date;

    public String getMessage() {
         return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Date getDate()   {
        return date;
    }

    public int hashCode()   {
        return date.hashCode() * message.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)   {
        if (obj==this)
            return true;
        if ( !(obj instanceof Comment) ) 
            return false;
        Comment other = (Comment) obj;
        return other.getMessage().equals(message) && other.getDate().equals(date); 
    }
```

I've not enabled caching for these objects with the @Cache annotation.

Why might this inconsistency be happening, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: You haven't shown any of the code which fetches this. If your fetch code is a query, it will show eventual consistency. If it's get-by-key, you're seeing something else - maybe you don't have the ObjectifyFilter installed?

Answer (score 2):

In short the data is stored with eventual consistency unless you are going to use an ancestor in your entities. This is by design. You can read more about it on [Balancing Strong and Eventual Consistency with Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/).

Comment: I understand that it takes time to replicate across multiple nodes with eventual consistency.  What I don't understand is that it can take more than 90 minutes.